# how to redirect the deleted lines of file to other file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a text file having fields with delimited by ',' symbol. I want to delete the lines having patters like 'S' and 'A' and redirect that deleted lines to other file and original file does not contains deleted patterns.

For example, say my file data is like :

```
S,F,T,Y
B,I,J,O
S,O,L,H
R,I,O,P
A,H,K,L
U,I,O,P
A,I,S,U
```

I will delete these lines and want to store it in separate file say delete.txt

```
S,F,T,Y
S,O,L,H
A,H,K,L
A,I,S,U
```

and file.txt contains

```
B,I,J,O
R,I,O,P
U,I,O,P
```

I tried with following code

```
sed -n '/S\|A/p' file.txt > delete.txt
```

This command is redicting deleted lines to delete.txt, but in file.txt contains deleted patters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 2 sed commands one after another:

```
sed -n '/[SA]/p' file.txt > delete.txt
sed -i.bak '/[SA]/d' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot......It is working fine.. I am new to shell, these informations  very useful to me.

Comment: Grumble: it does not require two separate commands to do this job — one is sufficient.

Comment: Works with GNU `sed`, but note that alternation (`\|`) in basic regexes is a non-POSIX extension, so it won't work with FreeBSD/OSX `sed`, for instance. The simplest fix in this particular case is to use `[SA]`, as in @JonathanLeffler's answer.

Comment: That is true, I was using `gsed` instead of OSX sed.

Answer (score 6):

On Mac OS X, `sed` requires an argument to the backup option, `-i`, so I'd write something like:

```
sed -i .bak -e '/[SA]/{w deleted.txt
           d;}' file.txt
```

The newline after the file name is needed, even with GNU `sed`.